# Stop ajax loader on ajax success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax loadmore pagination which works fine on localhost, but I am considering my method not applicable to live host.
This is what i am doing:

```js
     $(".button").click(function(){
       setTimout(function(){
         $('#loader').show();
         $.ajax({
           //ajax stuffs
           success:function(data){      
             $("loadmore").append(data).
           }
         });
       } ,2000);
     });
```

Technically speaking to me this is just taking 2 seconds to do what is inside the setTimeout function which is not right for user experience on the live server as ajax would be calling after 2 seconds.

What I want:

Let ajax call be made while the loader icon is loading. once the call is made successfully then the loader icon should stop and loadmore data should be appended.

Something like this:

```js
$(".button").click(function(){
   $("#loader").show()
   $.ajax({
     //ajax stuffs
     success:function(data){      
     }
   });
   if(success is finished){
     $("#loader").hide()
     $("#loadmore").append(data)
   }
 });
```

Please how can I achieve that, thanks

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you need, but maybe what you need is to use the 'done' method that occurs when there is a success in the ajax call. e.g. : $.ajax({...}).done(function(data) {console.log('Success!')})

Comment: Also don't understand what want vs what success:/.done gives you.  `if (success=isReady)` is what `success:` / .done is for.  Maybe some fixing of the formatting for your code will help...let's see...

Comment: Well, it's certainly clearer that your `.show` and `$.ajax` are in the setTimeout, but it's not clear why there's a setTimeout at all.  Use the second format (without setTimeout) / load the #loader before $.ajax / hide the #loader and append data in `success:` callback

Comment: "*ajax loadmore pagination*" is that a plugin or a paradigm?

Comment: "*while loader is loading*" - why is your "loader" not already loaded with the HTML?  You use .show() so should just be a hidden div/image.  What is "while loader is loading"?

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m for commenting, i will use your first logic and see what i can do.

Comment: My loader icon is loading to let user know that something is loading, so is hidden when in DOM but once the button is clicked then it is show at page bottom. The idea is loader is loader because ajax call isn't yet completed to append the loadmore  data. I think o get the logic to do that know, let me try your suggestion

Comment: How can i write the sucess.done function?  Whats the syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  $("#loader").show()
  $.ajax({
    //ajax stuffs
    success:function(data){      
    }
  })
  .done(function (data) {
    $("#loader").hide();
    $("#loadmore").append(data);
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
      // do something
  })
});
```

Comment: thanks, I later solved the issue, this also worked too :)